# find arcana: can't get pipe to work in -exec line

Tags: scripting, find, pipe

How do I pipe the results of a find through a sed to xform the stream, and then use that transformed stream as one of two arguments to a script? IE:

**find** turns up file1.tiff (among others)
**sed** transforms file1.tiff --> file1.jpg
a command is executed using both of these arguments: **convert file1.tiff file1.jpg**

I've tried this a number of ways and can't get it.  Here's one attempt that gives the flavor:

```
find ./out -regex ".*_p[bg]_.*tiff" -exec echo "Processing {}" \; -exec convert {} `echo {} | sed s/tiff/jpg/` \;
```

I should just give up and write a Python script to do each of these pieces separately, but I'm finally trying to learn UNIX tools and now am obsessed.  Help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure you can have a pipe inside `-exec`.  `find -exec echo {} \| sed s/tiff/jpg \;` doesn't seem to work.

If think your best option is to make a script to do the conversion, e.g.

**convert_tiff_to_jpg**:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Processing $1"
convert "$1" "${1/%tiff/jpg}"
```

and call it using `find -exec` like you had intended:

```
find ./out -regex ".*_p[bg]_.*tiff" -exec convert_tiff_to_jpg {} \;
```

There are a few ways to do it using `find -print0 | xargs -0`, but they are all quite ugly:

```
find ./out -regex ".*_p[bg]_.*tiff" -print0 |
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r filename; do
    echo "Processing $filename"
    convert "$filename" "$(echo "$filename" | sed 's/tiff$/jpg/')"
done
```

or

```
find ./out -regex ".*_p[bg]_.*tiff" -print0 |
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r filename; do
    echo "Processing $filename"
    convert "$filename" "${filename/%tiff/jpg}"
done
```

or

```
find ./out -regex ".*_p[bg]_.*tiff" -print0 |
    xargs -0 -I FILE bash -c 'F="FILE"; echo "$F" "${F/%tiff/jpg}"'
```

Note that I changed `s/tiff/jpg` to `s/tiff$/jpg` so that if `tiff` appears anywhere other than the end of the file name, it is not changed.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer.  Your tips will be a good jumping off point to learning more about BASH, too.  Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome.  On a technical note, `find -exec` can only run simple commands, not pipelines.  This is because `find` calls `exec`, rather than `system`, so no shell syntax is directly supported.

Comment: Just by the way, I'm pretty sure that using \0 as input to a read loop is redundant, and that its purpose is to allow a long commandline string (containing many \0 delimited args) to be passed to a program which is \0 delimiter aware and is only called **once**, but yet processes the **many** args internally; each in the same way... This saves a lot of time by avoiding perhaps thousands of individual calls.... A normal newline is fine for the read loop **unless any of the filenames have a newline char in them** ...Mhhh!?.. maybe I've just convinced myself that it is a good idea after all :)

Comment: The last one liner isn't ugly, it's pure art :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass a shell command to `-exec`, but what it takes is the name of a program and a list of arguments. So you need to tell it explicitly to launch a shell.

```
find ./out -regex ".*_p[bg]_.*tiff" \
     -exec sh -c 'echo "Processing $0"; convert "$0" "${0%.tiff}.jpg"' {} \;
```

- `sh -c 'shell code, not using single quotes'` is a relatively common idiom when you need shell features in a context that expects a command with arguments.
- `-exec sh -c 'do stuff with "$0"' {} \;` is a `find` and shell idiom. Some versions of find allow writing the `{}` directly inside the shell code, but this is a bad idea, not only because some find versions don't, but also because this can break horribly if the file name contains special characters (e.g. quotes). So instead the file name is passed to the shell as its 0th argument, and the script uses the shell variable `$0` to refer to the file.
- `echo tiff_filename | sed s/tiff/jpg/` is a complex, inefficient, incorrect and fragile way to alter the file name. It's complex and inefficient because you're calling sed. It's wrong because you're replacing `tiff` anywhere in the file: e.g. `tiffany.tiff` would become `jpgany.tiff`. It's fragile because it wouldn't work with some file names (some implementations of `echo` mangle backslashes). Instead, use `${0%.tiff}` to remove the `.tiff` suffix from the file name in `$0`.

Comment: Much cleaner.  I wonder why it's in `$0` rather than `$1`.

Comment: @Mikel: Process arguments start at 0, but the first argument (i.e. number 0) is conventionally the executable name, and shells don't let you choose it when executing a command. But `sh -c` lets you choose `$0` for the script, it's the first non-option argument. It might be cleaner to write `sh -c 'process "$1"' sh {}`. I like `$0` in situations like `find -exec sh -c 'cp "$0" "$@"' "$destination" {} +`, where you need one word plus one list.

Comment: Yes, I would have assumed it would start with `$1`, but you're right, it's right there in the man page. "*If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.*"